# My firebase remote config always give me this error: _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int')

Tags: flutter, firebase, mobile-application

Everytime when I tried to set default values or fetch/activate remoteConfig, I always got that error. This is my entire code. If possible, could I setup a meeting to troubleshoot it in more detail? Thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_remote_config/firebase_remote_config.dart';
import 'remote_config.dart';


void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
 runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});


 // This widget is the root of your application.
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     theme: ThemeData(
       // This is the theme of your application.
       //
       // TRY THIS: Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see
       // the application has a purple toolbar. Then, without quitting the app,
       // try changing the seedColor in the colorScheme below to Colors.green
       // and then invoke "hot reload" (save your changes or press the "hot
       // reload" button in a Flutter-supported IDE, or press "r" if you used
       // the command line to start the app).
       //
       // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
       // state is not lost during the reload. To reset the state, use hot
       // restart instead.
       //
       // This works for code too, not just values: Most code changes can be
       // tested with just a hot reload.
       colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
       useMaterial3: true,
     ),
     home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
   );
 }
}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});


 // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
 // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
 // how it looks.


 // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
 // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
 // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
 // always marked "final".


 final String title;


 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 var scs = "";
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   final remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;
   try {
     remoteConfig.setDefaults({'some_integer_param': '0'});
   } catch (e) {
     print('Error setting defaults: $e');
   }


   try {
     remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
   } catch (e) {
     print('Error fetching remote config: $e');
   }
   // getVal();
 }


 // getVal() async {
 //   var scs = await FirebaseRemoteConfigClass().initRemoteConfig();
 //   print(scs);
 // }


 int _counter = 0;
 Color _appBarColor = const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 159, 191);


 void _incrementCounter() {
   setState(() {
     // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
     // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
     // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
     // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
     // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
     _counter++;
   });
 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
   // by the _incrementCounter method above.
   //
   // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
   // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
   // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
       // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
       // change color while the other colors stay the same.
       backgroundColor: _appBarColor,
       // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
       // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
       title: Text(widget.title),
     ),
     body: Center(
       // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
       // in the middle of the parent.
       child: Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: <Widget>[
           const Text(
             'You have pushed the button this many times:',
           ),
           Text(
             '$_counter',
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
     floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
       onPressed: _incrementCounter,
       tooltip: 'Increment',
       child: const Icon(Icons.add),
     ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
   );
 }
}
```

I tried to double and triple check my syntax, and followed tutorials on youtube, but not working.

Comment: Check the answer what I submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It is expecting an integer value, but you are providing character value instead.

**Replace this line:**

```
remoteConfig.setDefaults({'some_integer_param': '0'});
```

**with this one:**

```
remoteConfig.setDefaults({'some_integer_param': 0});
```

Comment: I did and it still did not work

Answer (score 0):

```
String getRemoteValue = "";
Future<void> _fetchRemoteConfig() async {
try {
  final remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;
  await remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
    fetchTimeout: const Duration(minutes: 1),
    minimumFetchInterval: const Duration(hours: 1),
  )).then((value) async {
    print("RemoteConfig0");
    // remoteConfig.onConfigUpdated.listen((RemoteConfigUpdate event) async{
    print("RemoteConfig1");
    await remoteConfig.activate().then((value) {
      print("RemoteConfig");
      getRemoteValue = remoteConfig.getString(Platform.isIOS? "invitation_text_ios" : "invitation_text_android").toString();
      // });
    });
  });
} catch (e) {

  print('Error fetching remote config: $e');
}
```

}
I faced same error and fix into using these lines
_fetchRemoteConfig() call Inner InitState();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).